# Is there an easy way to get the duration of a a-frame sound?

Tags: aframe

I use A-frame and wish to play an animation for the duration of a sound (using the sound component). However I am unable to get this value. Is there an easy way to discover the length of an *.mp3 file? (Which currently is saved as a url-string)  Or will I have to use external libraries?

```
<a-entity sound:src="http://<website>.audioFile.mp3"></a-entity>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this from the sound component attached to the element you can write

```
var mySound = document.querySelector('#yourElement').components.sound.attrValue.src
```

then

```
var myAudioDuration = document.querySelector(mySound).duration
```

And the duration will be stored in that variable.

---

Alternatively, assuming your audio file is saved in assets with an id of 'myAudio' e.g.

```
<a-assets>
 <audio id="myAudio" src="path/to/audiofile.mp3"></audio>
</a-assets>
```

You can write

```
var myAudioDuration = document.querySelector('#myAudio').duration
```

And the duration will be stored in that variable.

I hope that helps

You can read more about audio/video tag controls [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_duration.asp)

Comment: Could also wait for it to load ```audio.onloadedmetadata = function() {
  alert(audio.duration);
};```